# How can I remove last typed digit from a UILabel?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

If I type numbers in a label, and if it is a mistake,
how can I remove last typed digit from a UILabel ?

I already put a button for removing the last digit from the label.

The name of the button is <kbd>back</kbd>.

[image]

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var lbltext: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var scrolview1: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet var fi: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var scrolviewus: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet var counterLabel: UILabel!
    var isFirstTime = true

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject) {
        lbltext.numberOfLines = 0
        lbltext.text! = lbltext.text! + "\n" + fi.text! + "\n" + "---"
    }

    @IBAction func back(sender: AnyObject) {

    }
}
```

Comment: In Keyboard, Press 'X' button

Comment: i think you don't understand me

Comment: Hi bozo, i've try to do an answer, you cannot intercept the exact moment ? What's the issue?

Comment: i don't understand what do you mean !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
@IBAction func back(sender: AnyObject) {
    if let text = lbltext.text {
        lbltext.text = String(text.characters.dropLast())
    }
}
```

---

Since you want to remove more than just the last digit added, keep the previous state of your label in a property called previous, and just restore it when <kbd>back</kbd> is pressed:

```
var previous = ""

@IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject) {
    lbltext.numberOfLines = 0
    previous = lbltext.text!
    lbltext.text! = lbltext.text! + "\n" + fi.text! + "\n" + "---"
}

@IBAction func back(sender: AnyObject) {
    if !previous.isEmpty {
        lbltext.text = previous
        previous = ""
    }
}
```

---

For multiple levels of undo, use an array to hold your previous labels:

```
var previous: [String] = []

@IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject) {
    lbltext.numberOfLines = 0
    previous.append(lbltext.text!)
    lbltext.text = lbltext.text! + "\n" + fi.text! + "\n" + "---"
}

@IBAction func back(sender: AnyObject) {
    if let last = previous.last {
        lbltext.text = last
        previous.removeLast()
    }
}
```

Comment: it's work but , not good it will be remove like this (---) = (--) = (-) i want to remove (---) with last number i add

Comment: i want to remove the last number with (---)

Comment: sorry man , it's just back for one time , can i make button back 3 times or more

Comment: I don't know how ? But I think I do it

Answer (score 3):

Objective-c

```
label.text = [label.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(label.text.length - 1, 1) withString:@""];
```

Swift

```
    if let text = label.text{
            let nsRange : NSRange = NSRange(location: (text.characters.count) - 1, length: 4)

            label.text = (label.text! as NSString)
                .stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(nsRange, withString: "")

    }
```

Comment: It will remove the last character you have enter in the lable

Answer (score 2):

```
 let name: String = self.display.text!
 let stringLength = count(name)
 let substringIndex = stringLength - 1
 lbltext.text = (name as NSString).substringToIndex(substringIndex)
```

Comment: `count(name)` is Swift 1. It will confuse all Swift 2 users. And there is a native Swift syntax to strip the last character : `name.substringToIndex(name.endIndex.predecessor())`

Answer (score 1):

Have you had just tried the delegate [shouldChangeCharactersInRange](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:)? :

Remember to do under **viewDidLoad**:

```
fi.delegate = self
```

Then call the delegate:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    if string.characters.count == 0 && range.length > 0 {
        // Back pressed
        // do whatever you want with your labels..
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: like what can i write if i want to remove last number i add

Answer (score 1):

```
@IBAction func back(sender: AnyObject) {
        for var i:Int = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++
        {
            if let text = lbltext.text 
            {
                lbltext.text = String(text.characters.dropLast())
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: try last digit and --- remove